# How to Convert base64 of wav or webm to aac base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, audio, recordrtc

I am trying to record an audio and store it in blob. I am using RecordRTC library for this. I am getting audio in Wav or webm format.

We have an app in which we have recorded and posted in .aac format.

I have tested recording same audio in app and web application. size of audio file varies by 5 to 6 times. aac file size is less compared to wav.

So i want to convert audio in webm to aac.

Can anyone Please help me, how to convert. It will be very helpful thanks in advance.